# How to prevent sending login/password on each request on a REST API stateless?

Tags: rest, authentication, authorization, stateless, stateless-session

A RESTful API need to be stateless, so we can't save context data on the server side. But, I don't want to send login/password on each request for security reasons. So, I would like to known if the way described below respect the article « 5.1.3 Stateless » of REST please.

> ```
> 5.1.3 Stateless
>
> [...] each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. [...]
> ```

Firstly, the client make an authentification request that return the ID of the user and a random authorization token saved in server side.

```
/auth/ { login, password } => { userID, authorizationToken }
```

Then, for next requests that require authentification, for exemple to update the user profile, the client send all the necessary informations including the user ID in argument, and put in the header of the request the authorized token.

On server side, we check if the authorization token in the header is correct, not expired, and associed to the user ID set in argument of the request.

Thanks for your help !

PS: I known there is another solutions like JSON Web Token, but this is not my question here :)